# MySQLdb downloaded but not accessible through Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mysql-python

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 & have installed anaconda2. Everything is working fine & I can access python packeges(`Pandas, numpy, scipy, sklearn, pyodbc`) through Jupyter notebook.

I wanted to connect mysql through python, so I tried installing MySQLdb via pip. I upgraded pip to 18.0.

From terminal, when I am providing the administrator right using `sudo su` I could able to import MySQLdb & connect to the DB I wished.

But surprisingly I could not import MySQLdb in Jupyter notebook despite multiple attempts. I really need to connect mysql from jupyter using any python-mysql connector.

As MySQLdb is not working, following other links I tried installing `pymysql`. But no luck.

PFA the screenshots & please let me know how will I get my jupyter working with MySQLdb.

I truly need that to happen!!! Please help.

[image: Linux_terminal_SS]

[image: Jupyter_notebook_SS]

Comment: As suggested in anaconda2, you *should* install any packages via the anaconda2 installer, and not via pip. That being said, if you do install it using pip, try the `--target` parameter and install the package in the directory that anaconda2 searches within.

Comment: Why are you running python as root user? Is jupyter running as root? If not, it won't have access to those modules

Comment: @cricket_007 yes jupyter running as root. ls -l shows jupyter is there

Comment: @musikreck can you please tell me how to install it via anaconda installer?

Comment: But **why** are you running it as root? `ls -l` doesn't mean anything for Python/Jupyter

Comment: @cricket_007 check out some guides [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html). If you have or are using Anaconda Navigator, there's a tab for the interface for installing packages.

Comment: @musikreck Thanks, but I know how `conda install` works. And it shouldn't require `sudo` to use, that is what I am saying.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to make MySQLdb workable?

Comment: Did you try : sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev ?